# IBM Text-To-Speech is not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I followed a tutorial to use text to speech with IBM Watson Assistant in Unity 2019.4.9f1. The problem is doesn't translated the text into speech, I did a few logging to see if it received the result from Assistant and it did but it's not turning into speech. I'm new to working with Unity and IBM Watson so I don't understand what's the problem. I tried looking up the error online but I can't find any solution to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

3 errors that show up in my console are these:

> [09/10/2020 20:44:58][RESTConnector.ProcessRequestQueue()][ERROR] URL: https://api.eu-gb.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v1/synthesize?voice=en-GB_KateVoice, ErrorCode: 400, Error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, Response: {
> "error": "Input contains unmatched open SSML tags",
> "code": 400,
> "code_description": "Bad Request"
> }
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Error(String, String, Object[]) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Logging/Logger.cs:280)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.d__33:MoveNext() (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:606)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Routine:MoveNext() (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

> [09/10/2020 20:44:58][Unity][CRITICAL] Unity Exception ArgumentNullException: Buffer cannot be null.
> Parameter name: buffer : System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Boolean writable) (at :0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor(byte[],bool)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.WaveFile.ParseWAV (System.String clipName, System.Byte[] data) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Utilities/WaveFile.cs:115)
> TextToSpeech+<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0 (IBM.Cloud.SDK.DetailedResponse`1[T] response, IBM.Cloud.SDK.IBMError error) (at Assets/Script/TextToSpeech.cs:218)
> IBM.Watson.TextToSpeech.V1.TextToSpeechService.OnSynthesizeResponse (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Request req, IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Response resp) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Services/TextToSpeech/V1/TextToSpeechService.cs:357)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+d__33.MoveNext () (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:646)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at :0)
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Critical(String, String, Object[]) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Logging/Logger.cs:295)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:UnityLogCallback(String, String, LogType) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Logging/Logger.cs:168)
> UnityEngine.Application:CallLogCallback(String, String, LogType, Boolean)

> ArgumentNullException: Buffer cannot be null.
> Parameter name: buffer
> System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Boolean writable) (at :0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor(byte[],bool)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.WaveFile.ParseWAV (System.String clipName, System.Byte[] data) (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Utilities/WaveFile.cs:115)
> TextToSpeech+<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0 (IBM.Cloud.SDK.DetailedResponse`1[T] response, IBM.Cloud.SDK.IBMError error) (at Assets/Script/TextToSpeech.cs:218)
> IBM.Watson.TextToSpeech.V1.TextToSpeechService.OnSynthesizeResponse (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Request req, IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Response resp) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Services/TextToSpeech/V1/TextToSpeechService.cs:357)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+d__33.MoveNext () (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:646)
> IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () (at Assets/IBMSDKCore/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at :0)

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed/ non changing lines you want to be translated into speech the best thing to do is to make them into an audio file and then import them into unity.
what you could also do is do the speech yourself and import it.

this is also helpful because then you can trigger the audio on a collision with other objects/points. for example in a tutorial level.

the other solution is to check your console i see 3 Errors and the rest just looks like warnings if you fix the errors the warnings will go away.

the first one looks like you have a bad request to the server, try another sml tag and check if it works.
the second and third one is the buffer, that should be configured in the code. so if you fix that you fix all the problems!